# How to search for directory in multiple servers?

Tags: linux, search, directory

We have defined home folders for a user in multiple machines. But the home folder is missing in one of the servers. How can I find out which server is missing the home folder?

for example, user name is: my_user
there are servers: host1, host2, host3, host4

/home/my_user is missing in one of the machines.

Maybe something like:

for host1, host2, host3; etc etc

Comment: What kind of remote file systems are involved? NFS, Samba/CIFS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop with `ssh` as shown below:

```
for host in host1 host2 host3
do
    ssh "$host" '[ ! -d /home/my_user ] && echo "Does not exist on $(hostname)"'
done
```